# WSGIDaemonProcess for each application instance

Tags: apache-2.2, daemon, wsgi

I'm using Apache & mod_wsgi to deploy a django application on several servers. I've read in multiple places (including this: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html) that it's better to use the Daemon mode of wsgi. This would allow me to have control over process count and thread count per process, among other neat things :)

Now my is that I can have two or more instances of my django application on the same server (with each its own settings, databases, etc). For example:

- `http://team1-server/prod-instance`
- `http://team1-server/test-instance`

Tough I think I understand how to use a different "process group" and "daemon process" configuration for multiple virtualhosts, i don't seem to wrap my mind around what i should do with multiple "sub-roots".

**EDIT:**

I run those under *CentOS 6.2* distros. In the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` directory I have one `.conf` file for each instance which looks like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /prod-instance /opt/wsgi_applications/prod/app.wsgi
```

**END EDIT.**

Should I use virtualhosts and have urls such as `http://prod-instance.team1-server/` instead? That would mean I should rely on the network managers to update the DNS tables, which is never fast enough for our clients. :)

I must admit I'm often lost when it comes to Apache configuration. Your help is welcome.

Thanks!

O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you are not using a very old obsolete mod_wsgi version, you can say:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess prod-instance
WSGIScriptAlias /prod-instance /opt/wsgi_applications/prod/app.wsgi process-group=prod-instance application-group=%{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess test-instance
WSGIScriptAlias /test-instance /opt/wsgi_applications/test/app.wsgi process-group=test-instance application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

If you are using a very old obsolete  mod_wsgi version, instead use:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess prod-instance
WSGIScriptAlias /prod-instance /opt/wsgi_applications/prod/app.wsgi
<Location /prod-instance>
WSGIProcessGroup prod-instance
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Location>

WSGIDaemonProcess test-instance
WSGIScriptAlias /test-instance /opt/wsgi_applications/test/app.wsgi
<Location /test-instance>
WSGIProcessGroup test-instance
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Location>
```

Comment: Hey @graham-dumpleton, could you enlighten me about what would be an obsolete version of mod_wsgi? I have the official package for CentOS 6.2, so that would be at least 3.2 I think. I guess that's quite up-to-date.

Comment: Version 3.2 is over 4 years old. That is not recent.

Comment: Oh yeah, CentOS often has old official packages. :-( But it seems it's recent enough to accept the newer syntax. Tested and accepted.